# Section overlap (header, main, footer)

Tags: html, css

I am doing my web project (front-end) and cannot fix this. The header and main parts are overlapping. If I change the position to relative, it will not have the correct form as it is now, or it will lead to the div content and nav being reversed.
Can anyone help me?

[image]

I want to fix this, not to let them overlap with each other.

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins:ital,wght@0,100;0,200;0,300;0,400;0,500;0,600;0,700;0,800;0,900;1,100;1,200;1,300;1,400;1,500;1,600;1,700;1,800;1,900&display=swap');
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  width: 100%;
  background: rgb(23, 23, 23);
  font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  min-height: 100vh;
  flex-direction: column;
}

header {
  position: absolute;
  width: 80%;
  height: 90%;
  /* border: 1px solid #fff; */
  border-radius: 20px;
  overflow: hidden;
  box-shadow: 0px 10px 25px -8px #000;
}

header::before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: url('img/money heist1.jpg')no-repeat center center/cover;
  opacity: .6;
  z-index: -1;
}

header::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: linear-gradient(180deg, transparent, #000);
  z-index: -1;
}

header video {
  position: absolute;
  width: 120%;
  height: 190%;
  top: -47%;
  z-index: -1;
}

header nav {
  width: 100%;
  height: 10%;
  /* border: 1px solid #fff; */
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
  padding: 0px 50px;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
}

header nav .logo_ul {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

header nav .logo_ul img {
  width: 40px;
}

header nav .logo_ul ul {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  list-style: none;
}

header nav .logo_ul ul li {
  padding: 3px 15px;
}

header nav .logo_ul ul li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #fff;
  font-weight: bold;
  transition: .3s linear;
}

header nav .logo_ul ul li a:hover {
  color: rgb(255, 255, 255, .7);
}

header nav .user {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

header nav .user p {
  padding: 3px 10px;
  border-radius: 20px;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  background: transparent;
  color: #fff;
  margin-right: 20px;
}

header nav .user p::placeholder {
  color: #fff;
}

header nav .user img {
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

header .content {
  position: relative;
  color: #fff;
  margin-top: 50px;
  padding-left: 50px;
}

header .content h1 {
  font-size: 50px;
}

header .content p {
  font-size: 11px;
  width: 350px;
  word-break: break-all;
}

header .content .details {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  margin-top: 10px;
}

header .content .details h5 {
  color: rgb(142, 230, 48);
  font-size: 10px;
  margin-right: 10px;
}

header .content .details h4 {
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 10px;
  margin-right: 10px;
}

header .content .details h3 {
  color: #fff;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  font-size: 10px;
}

header .content .details h3 span {
  background: yellow;
  color: #000;
  padding: 0px 3px;
  margin: 0px 5px 0px 5px;
  font-weight: 500;
}

header .content .details h3 i {
  margin-right: 5px;
}

header .content .btns {
  margin-top: 20px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

header .content .btns a {
  padding: 8px 12px;
  font-size: 15px;
  font-weight: 600;
  background: linear-gradient(90deg, #00bdff, #0079ff);
  border-radius: 5px;
  color: #fff;
  margin-left: 10px;
  text-decoration: none;
  animation: button 1s linear infinite;
}

@keyframes button {
  0% {
    background: linear-gradient(0deg, #00bdff, #0079ff);
  }
  12% {
    background: linear-gradient(45deg, #00bdff, #0079ff);
  }
  24% {
    background: linear-gradient(95deg, #00bdff, #0079ff);
  }
  36% {
    background: linear-gradient(145deg, #00bdff, #0079ff);
  }
  48% {
    background: linear-gradient(195deg, #00bdff, #0079ff);
  }
  60% {
    background: linear-gradient(245deg, #00bdff, #0079ff);
  }
  72% {
    background: linear-gradient(295deg, #00bdff, #0079ff);
  }
  100% {
    background: linear-gradient(360deg, #00bdff, #0079ff);
  }
}

header .more {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  padding: 0px 50px;
  bottom: 20px;
  color: #fff;
}

header .more .cards {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 200px;
  /* border: 1px solid #fff; */
  margin-top: 10px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  overflow-x: auto;
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
}

header .more .cards::-webkit-scrollbar {
  display: none;
}

header .more .cards .card {
  position: relative;
  min-width: 130px;
  height: 180px;
  /* border: 1px solid #fff; */
  border-radius: 8px;
  margin-right: 10px;
  background: #000;
  transition: .3s linear;
}

header .more .cards .card .poster {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border-radius: 8px;
  position: relative;
}

header .more .cards .card:hover {
  min-width: 300px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

header .more .cards .card .rest_card {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border-radius: 8px;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 999999;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: 1s linear;
}

header .more .cards .card .rest_card img {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border-radius: 8px;
  z-index: -1;
}

header .more .cards .card .rest_card::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: linear-gradient(180deg, transparent, #000);
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  z-index: -1;
}

header .more .cards .card .rest_card .cont {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  bottom: 10px;
  left: 0;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 0px 20px;
}

header .more .cards .card .rest_card .cont .sub {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

header .more .cards .card .rest_card .cont .sub p {
  font-size: 12px;
  font-weight: 400;
  color: rgb(255, 255, 255, .7);
}

header .more .cards .card .rest_card .cont .sub h3 {
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 12px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

header .more .cards .card .rest_card .cont .sub h3 span {
  background: yellow;
  color: #000;
  padding: 0px 3px;
  margin: 0px 5px 0px 10px;
  font-weight: 500;
  border-radius: 2px;
}

header .more .cards .card .rest_card .cont .sub h3 i {
  margin-right: 3px;
}

header .more .cards .card:hover .rest_card {
  opacity: 1;
}

header .more .bi-chevron-left,
.bi-chevron-right {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 3%;
  width: 25px;
  height: 25px;
  background: rgb(255, 255, 255, .3);
  color: #fff;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  border-radius: 50%;
  font-size: 12px;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: .3s linear;
  z-index: 999999999;
  opacity: 0;
}

header .more .bi-chevron-right {
  left: unset;
  right: 3%;
}

header .more:hover .bi-chevron-right {
  opacity: 1;
}

header .more:hover .bi-chevron-left {
  opacity: 1;
}

main {
  clear: both;
  width: 80%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: auto;
  margin-top: 25%;
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
  color: #fff;
}

main .events .promotion {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  /* border: 1px solid #fff; */
  margin-top: 10px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  overflow-x: auto;
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
}

main .events .promotion::-webkit-scrollbar {
  display: none;
}

main .events .promotion .discount {
  flex-basis: 33%;
  border-radius: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 10px;
}

main .events .promotion .discount:hover {
  min-width: 300px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

main .events .promotion .discount img {
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
}

footer {
  width: 100%;
  clear: both;
  background: linear-gradient(45deg, rgb(154, 156, 161), #2d2f33);
  padding: 40px 0 10px;
  border-top-left-radius: 125px;
  font-size: 13px;
  line-height: 20px;
  margin-top: auto;
}

footer .footer-row {
  width: 85%;
  margin: auto;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  align-items: flex-start;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

footer .footer-row .col {
  flex-basis: 20%;
  padding: 10px;
}

footer .footer-row .col:nth-child(2) {
  flex-basis: 20%;
}

footer .footer-row .col .footer-logo {
  width: 70px;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}

footer .footer-row .col h2 {
  width: fit-content;
  margin-bottom: 40px;
  position: relative;
}

footer .footer-row .col .email {
  width: fit-content;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
  margin: 20px 0;
}

footer .footer-row .col ul li {
  list-style: none;
  color: #ffffff;
  text-decoration: none;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 1250px) {
  header video {
    position: absolute;
    width: 200%;
    height: 180%;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 788px) {
  header {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
  }
  header nav {
    padding: 0px 10px;
    height: 15%;
  }
  header nav .logo_ul ul {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    left: 10px;
  }
  header nav .logo_ul ul li {
    padding: 3px 5px;
  }
  header nav .logo_ul ul li a {
    font-size: 10px;
  }
  header .content {
    padding-left: 10px;
  }
  header section {
    padding: 0px 10px;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 788px) {
  header video {
    position: absolute;
    width: 520%;
    height: 180%;
  }
}
```

```html
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-icons@1.9.1/font/bootstrap-icons.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <link rel="shortcut icon" href="img/favicon.png" type="image/x-icon">
  <title>MOVIES</title>
</head>

<body>
  <header>
    <video src="video/john wick.webm" autoplay muted></video>
    <nav>
      <div class="logo_ul">
        <img src="img/logo.png" alt="">
        <ul>
          <li>
            <a href="#" id="movies">Movies</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#" id="schedule">Schedule</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#">Tickets</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <div class="user">
        <img src="img/user.jpg" alt="">
        <p>Username</p>
      </div>
    </nav>

    <div class="content">
      <h1 id="title">John Wick</h1>
      <p>John Wick is a retired assassin who returns back to his old ways after a group of Russian gangsters steal his car and kill a puppy which was gifted to him by his late wife Helen. </p>
      <div class="details">
        <h5 id="gen">Thriller</h5>
        <h4 id="date">2015</h4>
        <h3 id="rate"><span>Rating</span><i class="bi bi-star-fill"></i> 4.5</h3>
      </div>
      <div class="btns">
        <a href="#" id="play">Details <i class="bi bi-play-fill"></i></a>
        <a href="#" id="book_main"> Book now <i class="bi bi-ticket-fill"></i></a>
      </div>
    </div>

    <section class="more">
      <h4>More</h4>
      <i class="bi bi-chevron-left"></i>
      <i class="bi bi-chevron-right"></i>

      <div class="cards">
        <a href="#" class="card">
          <img src="img/jurassic world.jpg" alt="" class="poster">
          <div class="rest_card">
            <img src="img/jurassic world1.jpg" alt="">
            <div class="cont">
              <h4>Jurassic World</h4>
              <div class="sub">
                <p>Action, 2022</p>
                <h3><span>Rating</span><i class="bi bi-star-fill"></i> 4.3</h3>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </a>

        <a href="#" class="card">
          <img src="img/the boys.jpg" alt="" class="poster">
          <div class="rest_card">
            <img src="img/the boys1.jpg" alt="">
            <div class="cont">
              <h4>The Boys</h4>
              <div class="sub">
                <p>Action, 2021</p>
                <h3><span>Rating</span><i class="bi bi-star-fill"></i> 3.3</h3>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </a>

        <a href="#" class="card">
          <img src="img/topgun.jpg" alt="" class="poster">
          <div class="rest_card">
            <img src="img/topgun1.jpg" alt="">
            <div class="cont">
              <h4>Top Gun</h4>
              <div class="sub">
                <p>Action, 2022</p>
                <h3><span>Rating</span><i class="bi bi-star-fill"></i> 4.0</h3>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </a>

        <a href="#" class="card">
          <img src="img/spiderman.jpg" alt="" class="poster">
          <div class="rest_card">
            <img src="img/spiderman1.jpg" alt="">
            <div class="cont">
              <h4>Spiderman</h4>
              <div class="sub">
                <p>Action, 2021</p>
                <h3><span>Rating</span><i class="bi bi-star-fill"></i> 4.3</h3>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </a>

        <a href="#" class="card">
          <img src="img/uncharted.webp" alt="" class="poster">
          <div class="rest_card">
            <img src="img/uncharted1.jpg" alt="">
            <div class="cont">
              <h4>Uncharted</h4>
              <div class="sub">
                <p>Action, 2021</p>
                <h3><span>Rating</span><i class="bi bi-star-fill"></i> 4.3</h3>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </a>

        <a href="#" class="card">
          <img src="img/thor love of thunder.jpg" alt="" class="poster">
          <div class="rest_card">
            <img src="img/thor love of thunder1.avif" alt="">
            <div class="cont">
              <h4>Thor: love of thunder</h4>
              <div class="sub">
                <p>Action, 2021</p>
                <h3><span>Rating</span><i class="bi bi-star-fill"></i> 4.3</h3>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </a>

        <a href="#" class="card">
          <img src="img/moon knight.jpg" alt="" class="poster">
          <div class="rest_card">
            <img src="img/moon knight1.webp" alt="">
            <div class="cont">
              <h4>Moon knight</h4>
              <div class="sub">
                <p>Action, 2021</p>
                <h3><span>Rating</span><i class="bi bi-star-fill"></i> 4.3</h3>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </a>

        <a href="#" class="card">
          <img src="img/eternals.jpg" alt="" class="poster">
          <div class="rest_card">
            <img src="img/eternals1.webp" alt="">
            <div class="cont">
              <h4>Eternals</h4>
              <div class="sub">
                <p>Action, 2021</p>
                <h3><span>Rating</span><i class="bi bi-star-fill"></i> 4.3</h3>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </a>

        <a href="#" class="card">
          <img src="img/avengers.jpg" alt="" class="poster">
          <div class="rest_card">
            <img src="img/avengers1.jpg" alt="">
            <div class="cont">
              <h4>Avengers</h4>
              <div class="sub">
                <p>Action, 2021</p>
                <h3><span>Rating</span><i class="bi bi-star-fill"></i> 4.3</h3>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </a>
      </div>
    </section>
  </header>


  <main>
    <section class="events">
      <h1>Events</h1>
      <div class="promotion">
        <a href="#" class="discount">
          <img src="img/events1.jpeg">
        </a>
        <a href="#" class="discount">
          <img src="img/events2.jpeg">
        </a>
        <a href="#" class="discount">
          <img src="img/events3.png">
        </a>
      </div>
    </section>
  </main>

  <footer>
    <div class="footer-row">
      <div class="col">
        <img src="img/logo.png" class="footer-logo">
        <p>Movie Theaters</p>
      </div>
      <div class="col">
        <h2>Office</h2>
        <p>Address</p>
        <p class="email">movietheaters@gmail</p>
        <p>Hotline: (028) 3775 2524</p>
      </div>
      <div class="col">
        <h2>Links</h2>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="" style="text-decoration: none; color: black;">Home</a></li>
          <li><a href="" style="text-decoration: none;color: black;">Movies</a></li>
          <li><a href="" style="text-decoration: none;color: black;">Cinemas</a></li>
          <li><a href="" style="text-decoration: none;color: black;">Events</a></li>
          <li><a href="" style="text-decoration: none;color: black;">Contacts</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </footer>

</body>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Absolute positioning is a **very** poor method of laying out webpages. It is extremely inflexible and there are much better and more responsive options. Check out [**LearnLayout.com**](http://learnlayout.com/)